# How to turn off the debugger in MIT Scheme

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

MIT Scheme's REPL automatically starts the interactive debugger when there is an error:

```
1 ]=> foobar

;Unbound variable: foobar
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 3) => Specify a value to use instead of foobar.
; (RESTART 2) => Define foobar to a given value.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.

2 error>
```

How do I turn off the debugger? All I want to see is the error message (e.g. `;Unbound variable: foobar`) without entering the debugger. In other words, I want to return to read-eval-print level 1 automatically whenever there is an error.

MIT Scheme version: 10.1.10

Answer (score 1):

MIT Scheme's interactive debugger can be turned off by running:

```lisp
(set! standard-error-hook
  (lambda (condition)
    (display (condition/report-string condition))
    (abort)))
```

To make the change persistent across REPL sessions, add the lines above to your MIT Scheme initialization file (`~/.scheme.init` on UNIX-like systems).

When there is an error in the REPL, the interactive debugger will no longer appear:

```
1 ]=> foobar
Unbound variable: foobar
;Abort!

1 ]=>
```